# Unable to compile pug program

Tags: html, css, pug, font-awesome, stylus

I'm trying to compile my pug program but receiving an error. 
This is the error I'm getting:
C:\npm\node_modules\pug-cli\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2490
  throw err
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (3:0)

```
-var sites = [
-  'facebook',
-  'twitter',
-  'google',
-  'instagram',
-  'dribbble',
-  'codepen',
-  'skype'
-]

.social-btns
  each site in sites
    a(href='#', class='btn ' + site)
      i(class='fa fa-' + site)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the indented block-style dash. This minimizes the chance of syntax errors and lets you write uninterrupted `JavaScript`.

```
- 
  var sites = [
    'twitter', 
    'facebook', 
    'google', 
    'instagram', 
    'dribbble', 
    'codepen', 
    'skype'
  ];

.social-btns
  each site in sites
    a(href='#', class='btn ' + site)
      i(class='fa fa-' + site)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!! Actually I tried to run this program on codepen.io and it worked there. What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe they use a more forgiving rendering engine? I thought it might be a spacing issue, that a `-` and a symbol cannot be touching. I thought `-var` would need to be `- var`, and `-]` would need to be `- ]`.